# SQL Server getting and updating the same records when using parallel library

Tags: c#, vb.net, t-sql, locking, parallel.foreach

I am running the code below which kicks off a couple of functions and in theory, both functions and all of the rows in the recordset happen in parallel. I am aware this is not literal but near enough as far as SQL Server is concerned.

The problem I am having is that when I get a value from a sequence table the same value is returned for multiple calls.  I suspect I should be using locks in the query but I don't have the skill to determine which lock type to use.

The SQL process is:
Get current sequence value/s to a table variable, There may be a request for more than one sequence
Update sequence value as increment
Return table variable

The VB.Net code shown is to help describe the parallel call, I don't think there is anything in the code that would be helpful to someone looking at this question.  There are a lot of libraries and most of them relate to models or calls to SQL, they are unremarkable and unalterable because changing them is not part of this fix's remit.

```
    Parallel.Invoke(New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30},
    Sub()
            If logEmailValues.KnownEmailAddresses IsNot Nothing Then
                    Parallel.ForEach(logEmailValues.KnownEmailAddresses,
                            Function(ByVal knownEmail) As LogMailLogResponses
                                  Responses.LogResponses.AddRange(New 
                                         LogMailExistingCustomer(apiContect)
                                        .AddCommunicationForExistingContact(ret
                                        , repo
                                        , knownEmail
                                        , logEmailValues.EmailDetails
                                        , dataService, traceService).LogResponses)
                                Return Responses
                            End Function)
                        End If 
                    End Sub,
    Sub()
        If logEmailValues.UnknownEmailAddresses IsNot Nothing Then 
            Parallel.ForEach(logEmailValues.UnknownEmailAddresses,
                   Function(ByVal unknownEmail) As LogMailLogResponses
                           Responses.LogResponses.AddRange(New LogMailNewCustomer().AddCommunicationForNewContact(ret, repo, unknownEmail, logEmailValues.EmailDetails
                                , dataService, traceService).LogResponses)
                                Return Responses
                            End Function)
                        End If
                    End Sub)
Return Responses
```

If there is a suggestion about the VB.Code I am happy for C# or VB to be given as I work in both.  But ideally, a suggestion of how to improve the SQL would be best, it is in the writing stage today so it is something of a blank check

Comment: I don't see any SQL code, are you using Entity Framework? If so are you sure the classes you're using are actually thread safe when used in this way?   Are you using the parallel foreach because your expecting the list of email addresses to be so large you can't process them single threaded?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have no code.  I think I said that in this case, I know what the problem is and the existing SQL is being thrown at SQL Server from the VB code.  However it is simply.

SELECT SeriesVal FROM SEQENCE WHERE NAME = 'NAME'

and then

UPDATE SEQUENCE
SET SeriesVal = NewVALUE
WHERE NAME = 'NAME'

But even if it was a stored proc it would contain little more actions.  There are several things I want to replace this with.  Stored Proc, Transaction, and some form of locking so that only one parallel operation can process at a time in the SQL Server.